# onClick loading bar not working

Tags: javascript

Trying to make a loading bar using onClick, but it wont trigger.

```
function click_01() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('trash_02');
    setInterval(frame, 10);
    var width = 1;
    function frame(){
       if (width >= 100){
            clearInterval(frame);
            width = 0;
       } else {
            width = width + 1;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: you are missing `elem.onclick = function() { // your code }`

Comment: I dont understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't clear the function frame, you need to give a variable name to your interval and then clear it.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('trash_02');
var width = 0;
var progressInterval;

elem.addEventListener('click', progressBar);

function progressBar() {
  // Name the interval to a variable
  progressInterval = setInterval(frame, 10);
};

function frame() {
  if (width < 100) {
    width++;
    elem.style.width = width + '%';
  } else {
    // We need to clear the interval variable
    clearInterval(progressInterval);
    width = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
#trash_02 {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id='trash_02'></div>
```

You can set your variables locally if you want, here is two ways of doing that came into my mind at the moment;

- Instead of frame() function you can define anonym function inside your set interval and define variables inside your progressBar() function.
- Or You can define your variables inside your progressBar() function and write your frame() function inside progressBar() function.

Comment: Why can i not make the variables local?